# store variables from dialog and pass to other div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a dialog box with a list of values. The user should be able to click to select multiple `<li>`s. Then, when they click a button, the text from each selected item is added to `#landing`

```
<!-- this is the dialog box -->
<div class="fontBox">
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="Button">Insert Value</div>

<!-- Previous Page -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="landing">This is where I want the value to go</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$('.fontBox ul li').on('click', function () {
   $(this).css('background', 'green');
   var nValue = $(this).val($(this).text());
   localStorage.setItem("nValue", nValue);

   if (nValue != null) {
       $('#landing').text(nValue);
   }
});
```

Comment: Is your table really on the "previous page"?

Comment: i mean its on the page thats open, not previous... so theres the page with a dialog in front

Comment: What do you get if you add `alert(nValue)` (or console.log) after `var nValue = ...`?  Seems strange to call val(text).

Comment: a value="0" gets added to li... is there is something there at least, I can go back and change what values get added, but im just testing at this point

Comment: Maybe change `var nValue = $(this).val($(this).text());` to `var nValue = $(this).text();`  not clear what that's trying to get.

Comment: What do you get with `$("#landing").length` ?  Could it be setting somewhere else?

Comment: in the developer tools it adds value="0" to each li i click, but when i write in nValue, it says its not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things that need to change for this to work. First, you need to handle the click of the button separately from the click of an `<li>` (I recommend a `<button>` tag here, but it's not absolutely necessary).

`.toggleClass(classStr)` is a great way to add and remove classes in jQuery and this is all you really need to mark an `<li>`. Then, you can get all `.selected` list items and concatenate their innards on a click of that button.

See my snippet below for an example. Note that I commented out your localStorage line since it doesn't work in snippets. Feel free to uncomment it in your own code. Also, notice that I removed your styling from the JavaScript code and placed it into the CSS. This is best kept separated like this. If you want to know more about why I recommend this, look up "Separation of Concerns" and/or just ask in a comment and I'll try my best to further explain here.

```js
var $liEls = $('.font-box ul li');
$liEls.on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('#insert-button').on('click', function() {
  var $selected = $liEls.filter('.selected');
  var nValue = '';
  $selected.each(function(idx, el) {
    nValue = nValue + $(el).text();
  });

  // Save to local storage (doesn't work in snippets)
  //localStorage.setItem("nValue", nValue);
  
  $('#landing').text(nValue);
});
```

```css
.font-box ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.font-box li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.font-box li:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.font-box li.selected {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- this is the dialog box -->
<div class="font-box">
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="insert-button">Insert Values</button>

<!-- Previous Page -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="landing">This is where I want the value to go</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this basically is doing the same thing, at least in developer tools

Comment: Try out this fiddle and let me know if that is the desired functionality: 
https://jsfiddle.net/51t56ghx/

Comment: This transfers the value to another div on click, what I want is the user to be able to choose more than one div so it needs to store the values, and then there needs to be a button where it adds those values to another div

Comment: So, if I clicked "A" and "C", should the text inside of `#landing` be "AC"?

Comment: Yes thats the idea, so the only way to do that is to store the values and have a button send those values somewhere else

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully, this is what you are after.

Comment: @Keith Perhaps you should, maybe, possibly, I dunno, **add this information to the question?**  Cause it really doesn't say that in the question and it's a completely different scenario.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have applied it as an edit. My rep isn't high enough for it to be immediately approved yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

What should this do in your code?

```
var nValue = $(this).val($(this).text());
```

It should be just:

```
var nValue = $(this).html();
```